# Sorting an array based on its value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an Array, 
Sample:

```
$array {
 [0] {
   [something]=1;
   [something2]=2;
     } 
 [1] {
   [something]=2;
   [something2]=4;
     }
 [2] {
   [something]=5;
   [something2]=2;
     }
}
```

I want to order the array based on the key something;

So it will look like:

```
$array {
 [0] {
   [something]=5;
   [something2]=2;
     } 
 [1] {
   [something]=2;
   [something2]=4;
     }
 [2] {
   [something]=1;
   [something2]=2;
     }
}
```

Comment: What sorting is this? Isn't the array just [reversed](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php)?

Comment: well in the example it has been reversed but the array is ordered based on the value of the key something, if you have a look...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function compare($x, $y) {
    return $x['something'] - $y['something'];
}

usort($input_array, 'compare');
```

you need to use a [`usort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) similar to the above.

Comment: +1 cause I didn't know this. I just wrote an algorithm to sort it manually!

Comment: Thanks works great and saved alot of time, i was thinking of doing it the complicated way

Answer (score 0):

Would the following suffice?

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    ksort( $array[$key] );
}
```

Comment: Ah, sorry - I thought that's what you wanted to do; sort by the key 'something'.

Comment: np, but thanks for trying, The solution is posted by dqhendricks